# JSHint Function Is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, use-strict

I am trying to write better Javascript / JQuery code and I set up JSHint with my Grunt.

Now I have gone though my code and its seems to be ok, without using 'strict'. I have split my code into many files, admin section, lib section (for my JQuery, Backbone) etc.

So I am trying to add 'use strict' at the top of one of my files.

Now JSHint is saying that a function within the success section of an AJAX call, is not defined? Now the function I have called in this section is in other file, but in my Grunt setting a build the javascript files up so the functions file is at the top, just below all my library files.

So my AJAX function is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getusers/"+SelectedSort,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
           EvenOddRows(".Row"); <- function in question!
        },
        error: function(fail) {
            console.log(fail);
        }
    });
```

So in my functions file I built the function like this,

```
var EvenOddRows = function (RowToColour) {
   $(RowToColour + ":even").addClass("EvenNumber");
   $(RowToColour + ":odd").addClass("OddNumber");
};
```

Its just a simple function the colour even / odd rows with an highlighter class.

This all works, but 'using strict' it says that me `EvenOddRow` function is not defined.

So I am guesting I am not getting something to do with the scope of functions, or is it just becuase the function is within the AJAX function? When I add `window.EvenOddRows`, then JSHint as now problems with it.

So what is best way of doing this?

If there is any code I have not posted, which someone needs to look at, then please let me know and I will post it.

*Please not that I am dyslexic, so I may not have explain myself right, if so let me know and I will re-word my question, thank you for understanding.

Thanks you,

Comment: Try to add EventOddRows to globals in jshint config.

Comment: Is that the best way? I don't mind re-writing my javascript to make it better, I know I use really namespace my code, which I have not done.

Comment: It's better to create a local variable in the scope of you function and avoid global function.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about what you mean by that. I am trying to get my head around Javascript scope